# Exchange 2003 (Outlook 2010 Client) Internel Distribution List Issue

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, outlook-2010, distribution-lists

I have a problem with Exchange 2003 and distribution lists.  When I post to any single user inside the company, I've got no problems sending mail.  If I use a distribution list, then the arrival of the mail at any internal mailboxes is very hit and miss.  Sometimes mail will be received, sometimes not.  It's not consistent either.  I have made a number of tests over the past two days and people who have received some messages have not received others.  Some have received them all, some have received none.  There seems to be no consistency to the distribution.  This only appears to be affecting internal posts.  External posts don't seem to be experiencing any problems.

I've got one PDC one BDC and a number of other member servers, and one instance of 2003 running on the PDC.

I've tried creating a new user and hitting them with a number of test messages.  Same result as the other members: Sometimes they get the messages, sometimes they don't when using distribution lists (Outlook 2010 Client).  Messages sent to individuals always works.

I've tried:

- Clearing down the local cache.
- Taking the client off 'Cached' exchange communication.
- Deleting all contacts and rebuilding a new Distribution Group.
- Deleting my mail entire mail profile and starting again from scratch.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all the Junk Mail filtering, and rules in Outlook to make sure that's not catching the mail somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the tracking logs and see if it is making it into the users mailboxes.
If it is then it's a local spam filter that is catching it.

If it isn't making it to the mailboxes though the IMF is probably blocking it, You can set up rules to white list specific body keywords or subject messages (or with some [workarounds](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Add_Whitelist_functionality_to_Intelligent_Message_Filter/IMF_%28Exchange_2003%29) email addresses).